# Does Ubuntu Touch have WebGL support?

Tags: graphics, ubuntu-touch, opengl, webgl

I would like to create a WebGL game for Ubuntu Touch, building on the HTML5 app template. Is this a possible option?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602223/does-ubuntu-touch-html5-app-framework-support-webgl same no answer.

Comment: @Rinzwind oh... right :(

Comment: @Rinzwind no one knows then?

Comment: @markkirby and you think I was not ;-)

Comment: I found no straight answer, but a site, if you visit and see the 3d cube you have webgl support. https://get.webgl.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a video from 2014 with Ubuntu touch and WebGL: Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zxk6nIlVeH8

[Wikipedia lists it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) and the WebGL website states:

> WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 and uses the HTML5 canvas element. Version 1.0 was released in March 2011 and some early adopters and users of WebGL including Google Maps and Zygote Body. Autodesk also ported many of their applications to the cloud, running on local WebGL systems. Some of the browsers that support WebGL include Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, and Safari. It is also supported by a number of mobile browsers including Opera Mobile, WebOS, and **Ubuntu Touch**.

So: yes.